# JavaScript: Constantly Switch image source

Tags: javascript, image, animation

My end goal is pretty simple. Once a page loads, I want an image to appear, but I want it to be constantly switching. (Ultimately, to make a fish look like it's bobbing up and down).

Right now my code looks like this:

```
var myFish = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

myFish.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(myFish, 100, 30, 200, 137);
}; 

myFish.src = "img/fish.png";
```

I'm not using JQuery, just straight javascript. How could I constantly switch back and forth between this image, and another image saved in the same directory.

Thank you!

Comment: If I were you, I would consider the `GIF`-format instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just have the 2 images in the markup and then show/hide constantly?

Comment: I should also mention I'm using HTML5 Canvas, and I am very unfamiliar with JavaScript....

Comment: I'll consider those options, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the timer functions

```
function updateImageSrcHere()
{
    //Update Image src
}
//Interval is measured in MS so 1000 = 1 second
var interval = 1000;
setInterval(updateImageSrcHere, interval);
```